# Check if another script is loaded without using JQUERY

Tags: javascript

I have two different that are somewhat depending on eachother (i.e one of the script has a function that calls the other script)

Now i wont go into any details other than saying i am not able to load one before the other.

Because of this i need to make a check in the scripts to check if the other script is loaded (So that the scripts "waits" for eachother).

My Boss does NOT want me to use `Jquery` so i was wondering is there a way in Plain `javascript` to check if another script is loaded? And if so how?

Comment: Just check if another function is defined? The task have exactly 0 relevance to jQuery. (Obligatory image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the function is already defined in the script which calls it, by doing something like:

```
if(typeof functionName === 'function') 
{
    // function exists so call it
}
```

That having been said, you'd be much better off to use proper error handling, by wrapping your code inside a try-catch block. So for example within the script that calls a function defined in your external file, you could try:

```
try 
{
    functionName();
}
catch(e) 
{
    // the call returned an error (likely because functionName() isn't defined).
    // Handle the error nicely.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response let me ask you a quick thing how would you make one of t he script wait for the other if the function does not yet exists?

Comment: Aside from using AJAX, you could just wrap it inside `setInterval()`, and then use a similar check to the first example I posted. As soon as the function becomes defined, execute it and clear the interval.